# No init.d file in the etc directory

Tags: 10.10, filesystem

When try to cd into `init.d` or less `init.d` I get an error message:

> No such file or directory

Where is `init.d` - why do I get that error?

Comment: Can you `cd /etc/init.d/`?

Comment: @Lekensteyn no i cannot - this is my question- why?

Comment: when i type ls-l inside /etc i do see the init.d - but can't cd inside

Comment: Shira, it's very unlikely, if not, impossible that you cannot cd /etc/init.d/. Did you run the command as I mentioned it? Did you follow these steps: 1. open Terminal 2. Type `cd /etc/init.d/` 3. You should be in. If not, please post the output of `ls -la /etc` on http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: thanx - it's do work now- i'm brand new with linux- my mistake was that i've typed in /etc  "cd /init.d"  instead of "cd init.d"  - didn't know the different between...........

Comment: @Lekensteyn you didn't write it as an answer- hence i couldn't choose it- sorry........

Comment: No problem, I upvoted Marcos answer too, as I have nothing to add to that answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a fresh installation of Ubuntu 10.10 I am able to `cd /etc/init.d` which is where `init.d` resides:

```
marco@img32:~$ cd /etc/init.d
marco@img32:/etc/init.d$
```

You'll need to make sure you are going *in to* the `/etc` directory if you are going to make any changes to `init.d` contents as `init.d` is a folder and not a file. There are various *other* folders named `etc` so ensure you are in the `/etc` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're in the wrong directory:

```
ibmux:~/proj/mini/forum > less init.d
init.d: No such file or directory
```

init.d isn't a file which can be seen by `less`,

```
ibmux:~/proj/mini/forum > cd /etc
ibmux:/etc > less init.d
init.d is a directory
```

do you mean `ls`

```
ibmux:/etc > ls init.d
acpid               failsafe-x                       nullmailer         single
acpi-support        gdm                              nvidia-kernel      skeleton
alsa-utils          grub-common                      ondemand           smartmontools
```